# Getting current working workspace directory of eclipse through plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am developing an eclipse plugin. But through plugin instead of getting current working workspace directory, its getting eclipse exe directory. How could i get the workspace directory through plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the root directory of the current workspace use:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

IPath rootPath = root.getLocation();
```

`IPath` has a `toFile()` to get a `File` or `toOSString()` to convert to a String.